# I'm trying to make an ajax request in a factory and pass the info in the json file to my controller. What am I doing wrong? See codes below

Tags: angularjs, ajax

I want to make an ajax request to a file (a simple json file that contains an array with string objects) on my local host from a factory i created. I want to pass this information to my controller which will also display the info in the view. Find my code below, what am I doing wrong?

//HTML CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ng-cribs</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.cs>
</head>
<body ng-app="ngCribs" ng-controller="ngCribsController">

  <div class="well" ng-repeat="crib in cribs">

    <h3>{{ crib.address }}</h3>
    <p><strong>Type: </strong>{{ crib.type }}</p>
    <p><strong>Description: </strong>{{ crib.description }}</p>
    <p><strong>Price: </strong>{{ crib.price | currency }}</p>

  </div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/angular.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/angular-route.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/uibootstrap2.5.0.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/uibootstraptpls2.5.0.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/ngCribsController.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/CribsFactory.js">
</body>
</html>
```

//app.js

```
angular.module('ngCribs',['ui.bootstrap']);
```

//cribsFactory.js

```
angular
.module('ngCribs')
.factory('cribsFactory', function($http) {

    function getCribs() {
        return $http.get('data/data.json');
    }

    return {
        getCribs: getCribs
    }

});
```

//ngCribsController.js

```
angular
.module('ngCribs')
.controller('ngCribsController', function($scope, cribsFactory){

    $scope.cribs;

    cribsFactory.getCribs().sucess(function(data) {
        $scope.cribs = data;
    }).error(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

});
```

//data.json

```
    [
        {
            "type": "Condo",
            "price": 220000,
            "address": "213 Grove Street",
            "description": "Excellent place, really nice views!"
        },
        {
            "type": "House",
            "price": 410500,
            "address": "7823 Winding Way",
            "description": "Beautiful home with lots of space for a large space!"
        },
        {
            "type": "Duplex",
            "price": 395000,
            "address": "834 River Lane",
            "description": "Great neighbourhood and lots of nice green space."
        }
    ];
```

See 
[My project file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmP5M.png)

The basic idea of the app is to get the information from the json file which is located on my local server and display the information in the view. But it just displays a blank page in the browser and displays these [errors in the inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkCU3.png).

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: `.sucess` - typo in the post or actually in code?

Comment: plus `cribsFactory.js` is not loading somehow.. that is what your console is saying

Comment: Also, `.success()`/`.error()` are deprecated - you should use `.then()`/`.catch()` instead.

Comment: I fixed the typo in .success and i agree to the fact that somehow the cribsFactory.js isn't loading and i have no idea where that is coming from. Also using .then() / .catch() didn't solve the problem either. Any different ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use **then/catch** instead of **success/error**
2. You are returning the promise that you are getting from
   `$http.get(..)`, neither you are chaining with response data nor you
   are using interceptors (assuming) to transform each results, so by
   default you will get the `response` objects when immediate promise
   resolves, so you need to use `data` property inside it.

Code of your controller should be like:

```
angular
    .module('ngCribs')
    .controller('ngCribsController', function($scope, cribsFactory) {

        $scope.cribs;

        cribsFactory.getCribs().then(function(response) {
            $scope.cribs = response.data;
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Koushik, so i tried using your code for the controller and still returns the same problem or at least similar results. I think that somehow the cribsFactory.js is not loading which i have no idea how to fix that considering that i provided the right reference to the files.

Comment: After trying @Koushik approach, it returned this ![error](/home/b4770u5541/Pictures/newError.png) in console.

Comment: what is the exact problem you are facing now?

Comment: Nothing shows in the browser and the browser returns these ![errors](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz8JvAI2BoaAcTlGWUhoZjRWLTg/view?usp=sharing)